# Defining a function once that appears in multiple name spaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, function-declaration

I am trying to define a common interface to a set of functions and classes that will have multiple different backend implementations (Using different libraries).

As such I'd really rather, simply, define a function in one place and not in each separate namespace.

For example, I have a global function:

```
extern void Func();
```

Now I want to have 3 separate implementations of that function.  One would be a straight C, One would be a hand coded assembler and one would be using library 'x'.

I am effectively trying to avoid doing the following:

```
namespace C
{
     extern void Func();
}

namespace Asm
{
     extern void Func();
}

namespace LibX
{
     extern void Func();
}
```

Is there a good pattern to avoid doing this? When there are 100 odd functions it will become much more of a pain.

The only idea I can think of is to move all the definitions into a header file that has no header guards and then doing:

```
namespace C
{
     #include "Functions.h"
}

namespace Asm
{
     #include "Functions.h"
}

namespace LibX
{
     #include "Functions.h"
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this that anyone can think of?

Comment: Have you considered using *objects*? Is there a reason not to define the interface as a base class and provide the implementations in derived types? --This is a bit against OO principles, but it would at least follow the Liskov's substitution principle.

Comment: Its primarily the non-OO principle-ness of it that has made me avoid it.  I'm not really encapsulating a state at any point ... Though, at least it would *force* me to implement the functions ...

Comment: I'd go for either forcing OO where it does not seem to belong (to obtain LSP) or opening the namespaces in each one of the headers/cpp...

Comment: There is also the added jump that a virtual table introduces and on one of my platforms such a jump will cause me an I$ miss ...

Comment: So ... you want to avoid *declaring* the functions multiple times, right? Because, with three different implementations, you will need three different *definitions* anyway.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a virtual function in an abstract base class. Implement it whenever you feel like it in a derived class.

```
class Foo{
public:
    virtual void bar() const=0;
}

class FooASM:public Foo{
public:
    virtual void bar() const{ ... }
}
```

etc.

Comment: Its a reasonable answer ... but I'd really rather avoid that virtual function lookup and jump ...

Comment: But the problem still stands that I end up with a fairly messy header file that continually redefines each function in each namespace ... I was just wondering if there was a neater solution to the problem ...

Comment: @Goz perhaps you can combine my answer with the curiously recurring template pattern to get rid of the virtual function lookup (aka simulated dynamic binding). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @MarcClaesen: Oooh ... I was wondering if I could use templates somehow ... will take a further look at that!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want static polymorphism - means a template or a macro:

Template:

```
#include "C_Functions.h"
#include "Asm_Functions.h"
#include "LibX_Functions.h"

enum Namespace 
{
    NamespaceC,
    NamespaceAsm,
    NamespaceLibX
}

template <Namespace> Func();
template <> inline Func<NamespaceC>() { return C_Func(); }
template <> inline Func<NamespaceAsm>() { return Asm_Func(); }
template <> inline Func<NamespaceLibX>() { return LibX_Func(); }

const Namespace NSpace = ...
inline void f() {
    Func<NSpace>()
}
```

An advantage is: You may have a common implementation for a specific function.
Similar you may do with macros (or you combine it)
I fear it ends up in #ifdef ... anyway, unless you try to have one lib for any hardware/system (which is pointless, in my view).