# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and statics in the base class

Tags: c++, static, crtp, static-polymorphism

So thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146206/defining-a-function-once-that-appears-in-multiple-name-spaces?noredirect=1#comment26577520_18146206) I'm looking at implementing my problem with CRTP.  However I have a problem.  In my static base class I have 2 sets of functions.  One takes std::vectors and one takes a standard C-style array.  So in the base class I define a static function that calls the non-std::vector function.

However when I derive from that base class I seem to no longer be able to access the public static function in the base class (Which I thought I could).

```
template< class Derived > class Base
{
public:
    static void Func( std::vector< float >& buffer )
    {
       Func( &buffer.front(), buffer.size() );
    }

    static void Func( float* pBuffer, int size )
    {
        Derived::Func( pBuffer, size );
    }
};
```

I then define the derived class as follows:

```
class Derived : public Base< Derived >
{
public:
    static void Func( float* pBuffer, int size )
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
};
```

However when I try to call the static function in the Base class:

```
Derived::Func( stlVec );
```

From the Derived class it throws a compilation error:

```
error C2665: 'main' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>          c:\development\Base.h(706): could be 'void Func( float*, int )
```

I assumed that I would be able to call a public static defined in the base class from the Derived class.  This appears not to be the case, however ... Can anyone suggest a workaround that doesn't mean having to implement the std::vector function in every one of my Derived classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func` in the derived class *hides* all base members with the *same* name. Use `using` declarative to bring the names from the base class into the derived class.

```
class Derived : public Base< Derived >
{
public:

    using Base<Derived>::Func;

     //rest..
};
```

Comment: Oh damn ... I thought it would only hide if it took the same parameters ... what a pain :(  Is it possible to import ALL the base classes functions using a "using Base< Derived >"?

Comment: @Goz: `using` declarative brings *name* into the scope. So you have to mention  *which* name.

Comment: And thats a "no" in answer to my question ... Seems a pain to have to put that using statement for every function though :(

Comment: @Goz: Not every *function*. It is every *name*, i.e `using Base<Derived>::Func;` will bring ALL members (whether they're functions, data, or types) with *same* name to the current scope.

Comment: Alas, in my case it will be every function :(